# How to run a guile Scheme script using shebang notation?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, scheme, guile

I have created a guile Scheme script using shebang notation.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/guile \
-e main -s
!#
(define (fact-iter product counter max-count)
    (if (> counter max-count)
         product
         (fact-iter (* counter product) (+ counter 1) max-count)))
(define (factorial n)
    (fact-iter 1 1 n))
(define (main args) 
    (factorial args)
)
```

File Name: factScheme.guile

I tried running it directly in the terminal "factScheme.guile" and I got *bash factScheme.guile: command not found*

If I used "./factScheme.guile" and I got *Permission Denied* .

I would be obliged if anyone can tell me how to actually run a guile scheme script in the terminal of an ubuntu step-by-step.

I have guile in the directory mentioned in the code. I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `factScheme.guile` file executable:

```
chmod +x factScheme.guile
```

Your program has other issues: you need to transform the *first* (non-program-name) argument into a number, and you need to *display* the result. Thus:

```
(display (factorial (string->number (cadr args))))
```

P.S. Guile programs typically use a `.scm` file suffix.

Comment: Thank you. It worked with a small change. I had to change car to (list-ref args 1) or (car (cdr args)), since car returned first argument which is the file name.

Comment: I edited it and added the comment to make stackoverflow accepted the answer. Thanks a lot though.